# References on the physics of anyons

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, anyons

Anyone know some good introductory references on the physics of [anyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the best recent references is the 2008 RMP article by Nayak et al. [Non-Abelian Anyons and Topological Quantum Computation](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.80.1083)

A somewhat less technical reference is [An Anyon Primer](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9209066) by Sumathi Rao.

There are many others but these two are good for someone starting out.

Answer (score 5):

Ady Stern, Anyons and the quantum Hall effect - a pedagogical review, arXiv:0711.4697 is a gentle introduction.

Answer (score 2):

In the presence of magnetic field, I like very much the contribution of [S. Ouvry](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/decembre2007.html) in the Séminaires Poincaré.